# Bootstrap css: trying to work with offset, but can't make to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html:

```
<div id = "search_form" >
    <h1> Need idea for your trip? </h1>
    <div class="input-group">
        <form action="" method="get" id = "search-form" >
            {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {{ form.media }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search_submit" name = "search_submit" type="submit" value = "submit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div
```

How to center it horizontally. I tried to use `col-md-offset-3` but no luck.

Comment: I don't see div with `.row` class in over your .col-xs-x classes.

Comment: When structured correctly, everything looks like you want. Row class should be inside container class div.

Answer (score 1):

To use `col-xs-offset-` classes you have to use div with `row` class over them.

This is documented on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Check details about grid system and then you will be able to position your content to center. Code should look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Half of width and position on center -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        your content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I read documentation. Thanks for recomendation. However, it's not working. Everything is pushed a little bit to the left

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
     <div id = "search_form" class="col-sm-6" >
       <h1> Need idea for your trip? </h1>
         <div class="input-group">
          <form action="" method="get" id = "search-form" >
            {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="col-xs-6">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {{ form.media }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="search_submit" name = "search_submit" type="submit" value = "submit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
 </div>
</div>
 <div class="col-sm-3" ></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, everything seems positioned a little bit to the left